# Jquery, Find a subarray that contains a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I would like to "push" a variable into a subarray which contains a value. This is to integrate into a "for loop". But it does not work ..:-( where is my mistake ? Thanks.

```
var add = "purple";
var val = "white";

arr = [
    ["blue","green","brown"],
    ["white","gray","black"],
    ["yellow","pink","red"]
];

subarr = [].indexOf(val) > -1;
arr[subarr].push(add);

/*
expected output :
arr = [
    ["blue","green","brown"],
    ["white","gray","black","purple"],
    ["yellow","pink","red"]
]
*/
```

Comment: Why should this be done with jQuery?

Comment: @VLAZ : Indeed, I should have put "javascript"...Sorry...

Comment: what should happen if no array is found?

Comment: @NinaScholz : With my function() (which I didn't show in the statement), there will always be a sub-array in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking

```
subarr = [].indexOf(val) > -1;
```

into an empty array.

Instead, you could find the sub array and if exists push the value to it.

```js
const
    add = "purple";
    val = "white",
    arr = [["blue", "green", "brown"], ["white", "gray", "black"], ["yellow", "pink", "red"]],
    sub = arr.find(a => a.includes(val));

if (sub) sub.push(add);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes !! It works like a charm ! This is exactly what I wanted to do, but I didn't know that you could put a function inside ".find()", I was happy to discover shortened functions (Arrow functions), and I didn't know about ".includes()" method. So I learned a lot today ! Thank you so much.